# Получить значение рядом стоящего тега

Tags: jquery

Всем привет есть такая верстка

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" class="order_other c-block cb-1 d-flex col-12 col-md-auto p-0">
  <span class="c-img d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
<img src="img/c1.png" alt="">
<img class="an" src="img/cc1.png" alt="">
</span>
  <p class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">Авиа и ж/д билеты</p>
</a>
```

Таких куча ссылок. У всех разные

```
<p class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">Авиа и ж/д билеты</p>
```

Но одинаковые `<a style="cursor: pointer;" class="order_other c-block cb-1 d-flex col-12 col-md-auto p-0">`

Как при нажатии на ссылку получить значения `p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".order_other").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).find("p").text());
});
```

Comment: Хотя с динамическими ссылками не сработает.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = document.querySelectorAll('.a');
const p = document.querySelectorAll('.a > .p');
for (let i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  a[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(p[i].innerHTML)
  })
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<a class="a">
  <p class="p">Авиа и ж/д билеты</p>
</a>

<a class="a">
  <p class="p">Что-то еще</p>
</a>

<a class="a">
  <p class="p">И еще немного другого</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', ".order_other", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log($(this).find("p").text())
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a style="cursor: pointer;" class="order_other c-block cb-1 d-flex col-12 col-md-auto p-0">
  <span class="c-img d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
<img src="img/c1.png" alt="">
<img class="an" src="img/cc1.png" alt="">
</span>
  <p class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">Авиа и ж/д билеты</p>
</a>
```